# If is None in python

Tags: python, tabs, indentation, if-none-match

I am new to python and getting a syntax error with my first program. Can you please help correct the syntax?

```
GET_CONTACT = "SELECT LINKEDIN_URL, CONTACT_ID from PERSON where LINKEDIN_URL=%s"

def isContactExists(linkedinUrl):
    cur.execute(GET_CONTACT, (linkedinUrl, ))
    return cur.fetchone()

if existing_contact is not None:
        storeInTempTable(record)
    return
```

Throws syntax error -

```
storeInTempTable(record)
                       ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#code-lay-out

Comment: As the error says, you need to fix your indentation on that line and align `storeInTempTable(record)` with `return`.

Comment: The reason for `TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation` is an inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are having spaces and TAB both into your code. Don't mix space and TAB.

```
GET_CONTACT = "SELECT LINKEDIN_URL, CONTACT_ID from PERSON where LINKEDIN_URL=%s"

def isContactExists(linkedinUrl):
    cur.execute(GET_CONTACT, (linkedinUrl, ))
    return cur.fetchone()

if existing_contact is not None:
    storeInTempTable(record)
    return
```